# How do You "Blockify" a Mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

Looking through some old .Blend files I came across this:
[image]

I remember making it the first time I heard of the poke function and then got sidetracked into experimenting with modifiers, but I have no memory of how I made it blocky shaped.

Can someone tell me how to blockify a mesh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Re-Mesh modifier set to Blocks mode:

[image: Example]

The Octree Depth attribute will change the size of the blocks (the Scale value gives finer control), a higher value and the more (smaller) there will be. Notice that the size of the blocks also depends on the size of your mesh, irrelevant of not applied scale, etc.

Comment: A small nitpick.. The Octree depth controls the number of *subdivisions*. It indirectly affects the scale of the blocks, but it's really more like multiplying the *number* of blocks.

Comment: @gandalf3 True, I should have that up front instead of later in the sentance.